# Assertion failure: movie player has wrong activation state (1)

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing a video (m4v) in an iPad app on one page, then it goes to a different View Controller which plays another video.
It plays fine, but when the second video finishes playing it then throws an Assertion failure.

The error is:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:], /SourceCache/MobileMusicPlayer_Sim/MobileMusicPlayer-1137.39/SDK/MPMoviePlayerController.m:1236
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'movie player <MPMoviePlayerControllerNew: 0x623f6b0> has wrong activation state (1)'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x015e35a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01737313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0159bef8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   Foundation                          0x001ea3bb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
4   MediaPlayer                         0x00522850 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:] + 204
5   Foundation                          0x00159669 _nsnote_callback + 145
6   CoreFoundation                      0x015bb9f9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0153a93a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
8   Foundation                          0x0014f20e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
9   MediaPlayer                         0x00521e08 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _postNotificationName:object:] + 56
10  MediaPlayer                         0x005293f7 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _ensureActive] + 158
11  MediaPlayer                         0x005242e8 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew setControlStyle:] + 45
12  Restore Sensor                      0x00073cfe -[MRSPresentationSlide2 viewDidLoad] + 334
13  UIKit                               0x00958089 -[UIViewController view] + 179
14  Restore Sensor                      0x00071ed8 -[MRSPresentationController pushViewOnScreen:] + 632
15  Restore Sensor                      0x0007395d -[MRSPresentationSlide1 moviePlayBackDidFinish:] + 365
16  Foundation                          0x00159669 _nsnote_callback + 145
17  CoreFoundation                      0x015bb9f9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0153a93a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
19  Foundation                          0x0014f20e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
20  MediaPlayer                         0x00521d24 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _postDidFinishNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 69
21  Foundation                          0x00159669 _nsnote_callback + 145
22  CoreFoundation                      0x015bb9f9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0153a93a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
24  Foundation                          0x0014f20e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
25  MediaPlayer                         0x0053d974 -[MPAVController _itemPlaybackDidEndNotification:] + 491
26  Foundation                          0x00159669 _nsnote_callback + 145
27  CoreFoundation                      0x015bb9f9 __CFXNotificationPost_old + 745
28  CoreFoundation                      0x0153a93a _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 186
29  Foundation                          0x0014f20e -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 134
30  Celestial                           0x025907a7 -[NSObject(NSObject_AVShared) postNotificationWithDescription:] + 176
31  Celestial                           0x02594a7d -[AVController itemHasFinishedPlayingNotification:] + 169
32  Celestial                           0x025989ca -[AVController fpItemNotification:sender:] + 2177
33  Celestial                           0x025a2a8d -[AVPlaybackItem fpItemNotificationInfo:] + 1473
34  Celestial                           0x02590f51 -[AVObjectRegistry safeInvokeWithDescription:] + 211
35  Foundation                          0x0016e94e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 251
36  CoreFoundation                      0x015c48ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
37  CoreFoundation                      0x0152288b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
38  CoreFoundation                      0x01521d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
39  CoreFoundation                      0x01521840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
40  CoreFoundation                      0x01521761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
41  GraphicsServices                    0x0304f1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
42  GraphicsServices                    0x0304f289 GSEventRun + 115
43  UIKit                               0x008b6c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
44  Restore Sensor                      0x00002121 main + 177
45  Restore Sensor                      0x00002065 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Anyone know why I would be getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem.
The first video was not removing the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification and so the second video was getting loaded multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple MoviePlayers, make sure that you register only on that exact player for notifications. e.g.:

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(moviePlaybackStateChanged:) 
               name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
            object:self.movieController];
```

This makes sure, that you only receive the notifications from the correct player.
That fixed it for me at least.

Comment: Hi, I am not registering for any notification, but am getting the same error (crash). Could you please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just Stop the Player Before initialise it Again .

[PlayerName Stop];