# Issue Playing sound from url

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am making an Iphone app which have requirement to play sound in a loop. The sound will come from HTTP links like follows:

- [Link 1](http://app.4uto.com/nsounds/scream/1.mp3)
- [Link 2](http://app.4uto.com/nsounds/scream/2.mp3)
- [Link 3](http://app.4uto.com/nsounds/scream/3.mp3)
- [Link 4](http://app.4uto.com/nsounds/scream/4.mp3)
- [Link 5](http://app.4uto.com/nsounds/scream/5.mp3)
- [Link 6](http://app.4uto.com/nsounds/scream/6.mp3)
- [Link 7](http://app.4uto.com/nsounds/scream/7.mp3)
- [Link 8](http://app.4uto.com/nsounds/scream/8.mp3)

Actually there are three button loop,play all and stop. I am able to do play once click all and loop but When i click other button app will crash.How can i solve this problem.My code is below resultArrayFinal is a globle array where all above sound link store.

```
-(void)replayVedio
{
DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:obj.soundInfo];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];


[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play]; 

}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 

{

 MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

if(_globle==1)
{

    [self replayAudio];

}
else if(_globle==2)
{

    DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];
    obj.soundInfo=[resultArrayFinal objectAtIndex:count++];

    if (count==[resultArrayFinal count])
        count=0;

    [self replayAudio];

}
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: i found same issue there in this quiz but there no solution given still http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766074/assertion-failure-movie-player-has-wrong-activation-state-1